# 17 definitions of algebraic K-theory of a ring. Which should I take?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

There are multiple definitions of algebraic K-theory, but I have trouble differentiating between them. Could someone help me out? Let $R$ be a commutative ring. I would like to define $K_n(R)$, and for simplicity $n \geq 0$ is OK for me now.

- The plus construction gives us $B\operatorname{GL}(R)^+$, whose homotopy groups give me $K_n(R)$ for all $n \geq 0$.
- The Q-construction takes as input an exact category $\mathcal{C}$. At this point we can pick the finitely generated $R$-modules, or the projective finitely generated $R$-modules, or the finitely generated free $R$-modules, or the coherent $R$-modules. This gives us four K-theory groups $K_n(R)$ for $n \geq 0$.
- All the exact categories give Waldhausen categories, to which we can apply the S-construction, yielding four more K-groups.
- Segal's construction involving $\Gamma$-spaces takes in a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$. We can take any of the above categories, along with two choices of monoidal structure, namely $\otimes$ or $\oplus$, yielding another eight K-theory groups $K_n(R)$ for $n \geq 0$.

Ideally, I'd like to see these definitions compared to modern ones. I've been told that one should think of algebraic K-theory as an $\infty$-group completion procedure, but I have yet to find a readable reference on this.

Comment: Little remark: The $+$-construction does not give $K_0$ which is of course quite crucial. That is also one reason that it is unnatural/ad hoc and which (probably) led Quillen to work on the $Q$-construction.

Comment: Which definition you want can depend on what you want to do with it. Are you working towards a particular result or area of research, or are you just curious about all the ways these things interact?

Comment: @KReiser I just want an overview on which is which, because it's all kinda confusing to me. That said, I am mostly after the plus comparison and how it relates to two $\infty$-categorical construction. Basically I have a stable symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category whose K-theory I want to consider, and I want to see if it can be computed by a variation of Quillen's plus construction. But then it struck me that I do not really know what any of these things mean...

Comment: The best way to say it is that all these constructions are deeply interrelated and equivalent. Maybe I will write down an answer later.
I will just note that the $\Gamma$ construction per-se doesn't produce $K$-theory. It is a delooping constuction. What this means is that if you throw in a group like monoid, it will output an sequence of deloopings for this space, so in otherwords it outputs some form of connective spectra from an infinite loop space.

Comment: So for example, both the Quillen constructions give you infinite loop spaces. The deloopings may be calculated via Segal's machinery.

Comment: If what you're after is the $\infty$-categorical formulation, let me suggest to watch Thomas Nikolaus' talks at the Newton institute on exactly this topic : http://www.newton.ac.uk/seminar/20180702113012301 (there are 4 lectures)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Sounds exciting..! Will take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me make a few comments relating the various classical constructions you mentioned.

1. The $BGL(R)^+$ construction produces an infinite loop space. It's constructed by taking $BGL(R)=\varinjlim BGL_n(R)$ and then attaching $2$-cells to kill the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1$ and attaching $3$-cells to preserve  the original homology. It might seem ad-hoc but there was good reason to come up with this construction. You can read more about the motivation in Segal's contribution to [the AMS tribute to Quillen](https://www.ams.org/notices/201210/rtx121001392p.pdf). The original source is Quillen's [seminal paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-Cohomology-and-K-Theory-of-the-General-Over-Quillen/3222ad37021a6865d419efcca92587cee37de07c).
2. The Quillen $Q$-construction is far more general and applies to a notion of exact category (i.e. an additive category with a class of exact sequences satisfying some properties), for example coherent sheaves or vector bundles over schemes. Essentially you take a an additive category $\mathcal{C}$, give it an exact structure, make a $Q$ consturction out of it i.e. a category $Q\mathcal{C}$ and then take its classifying space $BQ\mathcal{C}.$ The  $K$-groups are the homotopy groups of the loop space $\Omega BQ\mathcal{C}.$ In fact, $\Omega BQ\mathcal{C}$ is an infinite loop space.
3. In the $Q$-construction for a scheme you get two groups related to the category of coherent sheaves and the category of vector bundles. However there are theorems in the $Q$ construction of $K$-theory which allows you relate these two groups in nice cases. For example if you are over a smooth projective variety, then every coherent sheaf has a finite resolution by locally free ones, and by Quillen's Resolution theorem, the $K$-theories are the same. You can translate this to the language of commutative algebra if you want.
4. In the case of a ring $R$ and $P(R)$ the category of finitely generated proejctive modules, both constructions the $Q$ construction and the plus construction are equivalent i.e. $K_{0}(R)\times BGL(R)^+\simeq \Omega BQP(R).$
   This is the [work of Grayson](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Edan/Papers/HigherAlgKThyII.pdf), which he attributes to Quillen.
5. Then you have the Waldhausen $S$-construction, which is the most general of all which you mentioned. This is a functorial way to construct connective spectra as opposed to constructing just the infinite loop space. More precisely, for a Waldhausen Category $\mathcal{C}$, the Waldhausen $S$-construction gives you not only an infinite loop space $\Omega |wS_\bullet\mathcal{C}|$  but also infinite deloopings $|wS_{\bullet}S_{\bullet}\mathcal{C}|,|w S_{\bullet}^3\mathcal{C}|\ldots,$ and where $$|wS_{\bullet}^{n}\mathcal{C}|\simeq \Omega|wS_{\bullet}^{n+1}\mathcal{C}|.$$
6. Every exact category is (canonically) a Waldhausen categoy. In this case the $Q$-construction and the Waldhausen construction are related via a simplicial subdivision method called Segal's subdivision. This is proved in Waldhausen's [original paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0074449.pdf). Functionally this means that there is an equivalence $$\Omega BQ\mathcal{C}\simeq \Omega |wS_\bullet\mathcal{C}|.$$
7. Segal's $\Gamma$-machinery is an infinite loop space machine. It takes in an infinite loop space and outputs connective spectra. So for example you can feed it the $Q$-construction of Quillen and you will get connective spectra out. Note that the $Q$-construction already knows about the additive structure and in particular about $\oplus$ (the finite bi-poduct). If you also have a symmetric monoidal structure given by $\otimes$, over which $\oplus$ distributes , then your spectra inherits a coherent multiplication $KC\wedge KC\to KC$, where $KC$ is the $K$-theory spectrum of $C$ (in other words it is an $E_\infty$-ring spectrum).
8. Finally, there are several other infinite loop space machines such as May's delooping via the bar construction, but these are all equivalent. This is a theorem of [May and Thomason](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.6761&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Edit: A sketch of the $\infty$-categorical construction of the K-theory spectrum of a commutative ring (more generally a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category) is given in the appendix of the [Bhatt-Scholze paper on the Witt vector affine Grassmanian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06490.pdf).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks